# SQL View where value appears in one of two tables or both of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, both with the same columns.

The first table contains original source data, the second contains revisions to that data OR values inserted where no original data was present.

The tables are to be used in a view where if the data has a revision that is shown - if not then the original source data is shown.

Normally this would be OK using a Left join but it is the inserted revisions that are getting me confused how to do this best for performance reasons.

The following sample should help explain better

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (TimeStamp datetime,Value int)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (TimeStamp datetime,Value int)

INSERT INTO @t1 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-01',10)
INSERT INTO @t1 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-02',15)
INSERT INTO @t1 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-04',5)
INSERT INTO @t1 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-05',18)
INSERT INTO @t1 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-06',12)

INSERT INTO @t2 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-03',12)
INSERT INTO @t2 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-05',20)
INSERT INTO @t2 (TimeStamp,Value) VALUES ('2000-01-06',15)

--SELECT STATEMENT HERE
```

I need the output to be like:

```
TimeStamp               Value
----------------------- -----------
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 10
2000-01-02 00:00:00.000 15
2000-01-03 00:00:00.000 12
2000-01-04 00:00:00.000 5
2000-01-05 00:00:00.000 20
2000-01-06 00:00:00.000 15
```

So the value for 3rd Jan is present, the values for 5th and 6th have been taken from @t2 and the values from @t1 are not present in the output.

I am using SQL Server 2005 should that make any difference

Comment: Will you ever have multiple revisions/rows in @t2 please?

Comment: I won't in my case as @t2 in my real world code is a view on the revisions table that uses the most recent revision

Comment: ah ok, my solution may work with the base tables then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    isnull(tbl2.timestamp, tbl1.timestamp) as TimeStamp, 
    isnull(tbl2.value,tbl1.value) as Value
FROM 
    @t1 tbl1
FULL OUTER JOIN @t2 tbl2 on tbl1.timestamp=tbl2.timestamp
```

This is **Exactly** what you need. This is by the book and the only correct way of doing it. This is a trivial task, with just the right solution. Anything else would be much more complex, and slow.

Comment: Thing is I'm sure I tried this and it didn't work! 

One of those days I guess, thanks Alexander.

Comment: Just for future viewers, WHERE clause needs isnull/coalesce also e.g.

WHERE isnull(tbl2.timestamp, tbl1.timestamp) > '2000-01-01'

Comment: I have found that when using a FULL OUTER JOIN inside a view performance drops to basically unusable when the tables are large (many millions rows) and the NOT EXISTS/UNION solution provides better performance. As with everything your results will vary, just wanted to share my findings.

This is still best answer to the original question imo, especially with smaller tables.

Comment: It may depend on the RDBMS, but so far I didn't encounter poor performance issues with FULL OUTER JOIN (poor as poorer than other methods). One should take a look at the execution plan to compare performance, run the Database Engine Tuning Advisor for both cases, then see the results. Once I have time I will do so myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with a union:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.TimeStamp = t1.TimeStamp)
UNION
SELECT * FROM t2
```

Obviously, if the tables don't have identical structures, then you need to explicitly list columns (and it's probably good practice to do so anyway).

Comment: that's called Full Outer Join. Instead of these 3 words you wrote a union, and a NOT EXIST clause, totalling to 3 different selects.

Comment: Good point. However, an outer join would produce a result set containing each column twice (once from t1, and once from t2), with either side possibly NULL. You'd have to add some extra effort to get them into two columns (e.g. an ISNULL() around each).